# How to use setCPUFrac in mininet?

Tags: mininet

I'm using Mininet to emulate a simple network with `sudo mn`, which creates a two hosts network. Now I want to allocate a specific CPU rate for each host. 
I know this is possible by using `setCPUFrac`, but I couldn't manage to use it successfully.

How to use the function from the command line? I tried things like :

```
h1 setCPUFrac( f=-1,sched=None)
h1 setCPUFrac(f="1")
h1 setCPUFrac(f=1)
setCPUFrac(h1, f=-1,sched=None)
```

and all gave me :

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token
```

Note: I'm new to Mininet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command that you run, executes *setCPUFrac( f=-1,sched=None)* on *h1*, that's why you have a bash error.

You need to be sure that the host Type is **CPULimitedHost** otherwise, it doesn't have the method *setCPUFrac*

From the **mn** command line you can run the network using the limited hosts with *--host cfs,sched=None* and then use the *py* command to do the trick in the mn command line.

i.e.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# mn  --host cfs,sched=None
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> py net.getNodeByName("h1").setCPUFrac( f=-1,sched=None)
mininet>
```

Or you can build a python script following the [mininet API](http://mininet.org/api/annotated.html)

Comment: What if my network is already built without using `--host cfs,sched=None`? Can i edit this from Mininet CLI?

Comment: --host cfs,sched=None creates the CPULimitedHost, the normal hosts don' t have the method .setCPUFrac() so it will raise an error.
If you are building the network using a python script, you have to do:  from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, and use it when you declare the network i.e. net=Mininet(topo=YourTopo, host=CPULimitedHost )